# Date is showing invalid in IE browser but works good with chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, momentjs

The date is saved as  UTC in database. Fetching date from database sql - column type is DateTime.

```
moment(moment.utc('@item.PublishedDate').toDate()).format('Do MMM YYYY hh:mm A')
```

In my local system IE shows the date but in test server it shows "invalid date"

[Screenshot for inspect page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sscJO.jpg)

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: I am using IE11

Comment: `moment.utc('@item.PublishedDate').toDate()` is diffent from the code in the image, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Moreover [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) docs could help you.

Comment: @VincenzoC image is updated

Comment: You have to use `moment('22-Feb-19 10:12:49 AM', 'DD-MMM-YY hh:mm:ss A')` to parse `'22-Feb-19 10:12:49 AM'`. Please, prefer sharing code instead of images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date is coming back in a format not supported by moment. `22-Feb-19 10:12:49 AM`. To get moment to understand this you need to tell it the format:

```
moment.utc('22-Feb-19 10:12:49 AM', 'DD-MMM-YY hh:mm:ss a')
```

Below is a runnable snippet.

```js
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = moment.utc('22-Feb-19 10:12:49 AM', 'DD-MMM-YY hh:mm:ss a').local().format('Do MMM YYYY hh:mm A')
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: My inspect image is updated now...i tried your third method and it is not working..please refer the new image updated

Comment: @Iam_NSA you need to tell moment the format to expect, answer has been updated.

Comment: In your snippet result the date is not getting localized..In my question i want to convert utc to local

Comment: So use ‘.local()’